# How to detect Y position of StackLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using mechanism to move Stacklayout with gestures.  Is there another event that detects StackLayout's Y position change?  Meaning that I would like to catch when the StackLayout position is being panned up or down.

```
   <StackLayout x:Name="bottomDrawer" BackgroundColor="Olive" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1.00,0.9,0.04" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureHandler" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `PropertyChanging` and `PropertyChanged` events on the `BindableObject` (which is a class within the `StackLayout` hierarchy).

So you could bind to change(s) on the `Y`, `Height` and/or `LayoutBounds` properties.

Example using events:

```
aStackLayoutObject.PropertyChanging += (sender, e) =>
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Y":
            Log.WriteLine($"{e.PropertyName} : {(sender as StackLayout).Y}");
            break;
        case "Height":
            Log.WriteLine($"{e.PropertyName} : {(sender as StackLayout).Height}");
            break;
        case "LayoutBounds":
            Log.WriteLine($"{e.PropertyName}";
            break;
};

aStackLayoutObject.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Y":
            Log.WriteLine($"{e.PropertyName} : {(sender as StackLayout).Y}");
            break;
        case "Height":
            Log.WriteLine($"{e.PropertyName} : {(sender as StackLayout).Height}");
            break;
        case "LayoutBounds":
            Log.WriteLine($"{e.PropertyName}";
            break;
};
```